# Spark : Parse StringType column and create two new columns with DoubleType and StringType as per the value in input column

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

[Input_Output_image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b6iwl.jpg)

As shown in image Input DF having a column "ColumnValues" with String values and needs to create output data frame with two columns "VALUE_NUMBER" and "VALUE_STRING", which must contain value after parsing "ColumnValues" string. If it is string value it should go to "VALUE_STRING" column and if it is number value it should go to "VALUE_NUMBER" column. I have very huge data and need to create this output efficiently.

Comment: Rajesh, I have added solution check once .. accept or upvote if it helps .. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `cast` & `when`

Cast the value to `double` if it is able to cast the double value successfully it will return the `number` else `null` then check this `null` inside `when` function.

Check below code.

**Solution 1**  - using `withColumn` & `when`

```
scala> df.show(false)
+------------+
|columnvalues|
+------------+
|Maharashtra |
|23432.53    |
|Karnataka   |
|424244      |
|Goa         |
+------------+

scala> df
.withColumn("value_number",when(
        !$"columnvalues".cast("double").isNull,
        $"columnvalues"
    ).otherwise(0.0)
)
.withColumn("value_string",when(
        $"columnvalues".cast("double").isNull,
        $"columnvalues"
    ).otherwise("")
)
.show(false)
+------------+------------+------------+
|columnvalues|value_number|value_string|
+------------+------------+------------+
|Maharashtra |0.0         |Maharashtra |
|23432.53    |23432.53    |            |
|Karnataka   |0.0         |Karnataka   |
|424244      |424244      |            |
|Goa         |0.0         |Goa         |
+------------+------------+------------+
```

**Solution 2** - Using `when` inside `select`

```
df.select(
    $"columnvalues",
    when(!$"columnvalues".cast("double").isNull,$"columnvalues").otherwise(0.0).as("value_number"),
    when($"columnvalues".cast("double").isNull,$"columnvalues").otherwise("").as("value_string")
)
.show(false)

+------------+------------+------------+
|columnvalues|value_number|value_string|
+------------+------------+------------+
|Maharashtra |0.0         |Maharashtra |
|23432.53    |23432.53    |            |
|Karnataka   |0.0         |Karnataka   |
|424244      |424244      |            |
|Goa         |0.0         |Goa         |
+------------+------------+------------+
```

**Solution 3** - Using `when` & `struct`

```
val expr = when(
        !$"columnvalues".cast("double").isNull,
        struct(
            $"columnvalues".cast("double").as("value_number"),
            lit("").as("value_string")
        )
    ).otherwise(
        struct(
            lit(0.0).cast("double").as("value_number"),
            $"columnvalues".as("value_string")
        )
    ).as("value")

scala> df.select($"columnvalues",expr).select($"columnvalues",$"value.*").show(false)
+------------+------------+------------+
|columnvalues|value_number|value_string|
+------------+------------+------------+
|Maharashtra |0.0         |Maharashtra |
|23432.53    |23432.53    |            |
|Karnataka   |0.0         |Karnataka   |
|424244      |424244.0    |            |
|Goa         |0.0         |Goa         |
+------------+------------+------------+
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it via simple mapping function as below,

1. Load your dataframe
2. Try mapping to double
3. If its a success map cast it explicitly else assign 0.0
4. If double casting fails cast it to string or empty string

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession

import scala.util.Try

object MapToMultiColumns {

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {

    val spark = SparkSession.builder.master("local[*]").getOrCreate;

    import spark.implicits._

    val df = List("Maharashtra","23432.53","Karnataka","424244","Goa").toDF("columnvalues")

    df.map(row => {
      val isDouble = Try(row.getString(0).toDouble).isSuccess
      val value_number : Double = if(isDouble) row.getString(0).toDouble else 0.0
      val value_string : String = if(!isDouble) row.getString(0) else ""

      (row.getString(0),value_number,value_string)
    }).toDF("columnvalues","value_number","value_string")
      .show()

  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried with a similar example

```
import pandas as pd
 cars = ['Honda Civic','Toyota Corolla','2000','30000','Ford Focus','Audi A4']
df = pd.DataFrame(cars, columns = ['Brand'])
df['brand_str'] = df.loc[~df['Brand'].astype(str).str.isdigit(),'Brand']
df['brand_int'] = df.loc[df['Brand'].str.isdigit(), 'Brand'] 
values = {'brand_str': '', 'brand_int': 0.0} 
df.fillna(value=values)
```

I hope this works too for your data.

```
  Brand        brand_str         brand_int
0   Honda Civic    Honda Civic          0.0
1   Toyota Corolla  Toyota Corolla      0.0
2   2000                               2000
3   30000                              30000
4   Ford Focus       Ford Focus        0.0
5   Audi A4          Audi A4           0.0
```